# No module named 'fbprophet' in jupyter notebook inside visual studio code though it is listed in pip3 list

Tags: python, pystan, facebook-prophet

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cwx1.png)

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 from fbprophet import Prophet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'

Comment: wrong python version perhaps?

Comment: python 3.8.3 is installed